# Jenkins - Creating parallel ipa build creation for multiple targets for iOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have one iOS Application projects with a huge number of targets lets say 30, we can build targets individually or one by one through Jenkins, but this take huge time like 5-6 hrs since it has to generate 30 IPA. So is there any alternate way to parallelly generate multiple ipa's using Jenkin's? Help me out with any possible tutorials or examples. Or with MultiJob plugin how we should do it with an example.